# Strange thing happens with SKSpriteNode with transparent borders

Tags: sprite-kit, skspritenode

Ok, I have this code:

```
        SKSpriteNode *flagTile = [((BGSKView *) self.skView).tileSprites[@"flag"] copy];
        flagTile.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
        flagTile.size = touchedNode.size;
        flagTile.name = @"flag";

        [touchedNode addChild:flagTile];
```

When user taps a field (an SKSpriteNode) it adds one more sprite to its children - flag node.
touchedNode texture size is 80x80, flag texture is 80x80... they are totally equal, the main difference is that the flag texture has transparent borders.

Here:

[image]

But strange thing happens: flag node is *always* has its *real* (lets call it "tappable") area smaller than the touchedNode and its position is kind a weird thing.

Like so:

[image]

The structure of my all layers are like this: compoundNode contains two layers - A and B. When resize of the whole tree is needed xScale and yScale is set (compoundNode). No other manipulations with sizes.

What am I doing wrong?

What I really need is to have my flagTile tappable area to be the size of touchedNode. And one more: if I replace:

```
SKSpriteNode *flagTile = [((BGSKView *) self.skView).tileSprites[@"flag"] copy];
```

with this one:

```
SKSpriteNode *flagTile = [SKSpriteNode spriteWithColor:[UIColor clearColor] size:touchedNode.size];
```

it works great.

I have tried even changing the texture property after created clearColor sprite - nothing works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `SKSpriteNode *flagTile = [((BGSKView *) self.skView).tileSprites[@"flag"] copy];` is creating your sprite but is ignoring the invisible parts around the flag. When I open your flag image in my image editor (Adobe Fireworks) and select your flag, only the actual flag rect gets selected (look at the image I posted).

The only workaround I can think of is for you to add a white (or any color you want) square behind the flag with a size of 80,80. Then set the alpha of the square to 1 point above completely transparent. I think this should allow for the entire 80 by 80 image to be touchable.

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thank you, but it this really the only solution? What if I have had more complicated graphic which needed to use transparent images with borders and no additional colors?

Comment: That all depends on your code structure. There are a couple of things you can do. Instead of using an alpha+1 layer, you could put a tiny dot into diagonal corners. Another cleaner option is to just use the sprite node as is and add a larger invisible node over it to handle touching.

Comment: You could use your flag image to create an alpha of the flag (this should be a white flag on a black background) you can then combine this in Photoshop to create a 32bit PNG file. Note it's probably best to put the main flag on a solid background too, the color does not matter as it will be removed by the alpha anyways. That way you don't end up with corner dots and the sizing is taken from the full image (with no transparent pixels)

Comment: @sangony I think the best answer here is to add transparent node with clear color and right size. Cleaner and easy way to implement. You can edit your answer and thanks for info.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem by adding two dots in two corners (left-lower and right-upper) with opacity set to 1% and it worked great.